# Using Pycharm to connect to cluster 'ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, gpu

I want to use Pycharm on my own laptop to connect to our `linux cluster` and use `tensorflow-gpu` on it.
However, it says:

> ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory.

When I use `terminal` to connect to cluster and use tensorflow GPU through terminal,there's no problem.
However ,when I use `python remote interpreter` in `Pycharm`,the error happens when importing tensorflow-gpu :

> ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory
>   Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

The location 'libcuda.so.1' on the cluster is

> '/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1'

and

> '/usr/lib64/libcuda.so.1'.

I tried to add them as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `Environment variables` in `Pycharm run configuration` :

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/libcuda.so.1\;/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1

but it doesn't work.
I can use other packages like `numpy`,`sklearn` normally.

What's more,the corresponding version of my Tensorflow GPU is `CUDA 9.0`.If the error is about CUDA,it should be like can not find `libcuda.so.9`,however it shows `libcuda.so.1`.

I can also use tensorflow-GPU through terminal and ssh well,so I think the problem might be from `Pycharm` settings?
What do I need to do about `Pycharm` settings apart from adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH to Environment variables?

Comment: add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your run configuration in pycharm

Comment: Thank you. Actually I did so but it didn't work...

Comment: I would recommend just running your .bashrc before launching the sciprt https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000485930-PyCharm-remote-interpreter-and-environment-variables